# Bind rotation of content to the rotation of ancestor

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to create a control with customized content.
The text inside should be rotated in the opposite direction to always be displayed vertically. To do this I have to bind rotation angle of text to rotation angle of text ancestor. How to do it? Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. The important thing is to invert the rotation direction by two mirror transforms, before and after the child element rotation.

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue" Width="200" Height="200"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="Hello" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RenderTransform.Angle,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Panel}}"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```